# Firebase notification are not working in chrome incognito mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I open the chrome browser in incognito mode then service worker file execute then get an error.

Getting Following error

```
messaging/permission-blocked"
message:"Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked)."
stack:"FirebaseError: Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked).↵ at d (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-messaging.js:30:200)"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notifications to Chrome using Firebase Cloud Messaging are disabled in incognito mode.

Interestingly enough, the best link I can find for it is in the OneSignal documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-setup

Answer (score 7):

This is largely dependent on the browser.

The reasoning from the Chrome side is that the expectation is unclear from the users point of view. If you enable push in an incognito window and then close it, should you still receive push messages?

In Firefox I had a number of problems diagnosing an unusual setting I had on where Firefox would **not** write any files to disk, this lead to service workers not being install-able, even though the API was there, took a while to learn it was the security setting that was the issue.

Comment: This does not seem to be a limitation of Firebase Realtime DB. Is there a lower level shared mechanism to send data payloads to browser client w/o having to prompt for permission? I'm not trying to display notifications, just respond to arbitrary events.